# jQuery Validate Regx capture groups

Tags: javascript, regex

I am looking to validate a text field using jQuery validate but it must be in the following format:

(letters and numbers only)optional space(-)optional space(letters and numbers only)optional space(-)optional space(numbers only)optional space(-)optional space(numbers YYYY)

So far I have:

```
/^(a-zA-Z)\s(-)\s(a-zA-Z)\s(-)\s(\d+)\s(-)\s(0-9){4}$/
```

Comment: Show some valid and invalid sample inputs. Also, what is your question?

Comment: Solution: learn Regular Expressions. I really recommend YouTube!

Comment: a valid input would be - BMW - 120D - 2000 - 2017 (make, model, engine size, year)

Comment: You might read about [character classes](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [optional items](https://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following regex for your question :

Find working regex here: https://regex101.com/r/CjX5BE/1

```
/^([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*(-)\s*([a-zA-Z0-9]*)\s*(-)\s*([0-9]*)\s*(-)\s*([0-9]{1,4})/
```

This is parsed: BMW - 120D - 2000 - 2017

Comment: There are a lot of optional parts in the pattern. It would for example also match `---2` I think you can omit the capturing groups and repeat the character class + times `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?- ?[a-zA-Z0-9]+ ?- ?[0-9]+ ?- ?[0-9]{1,4}$`  [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/AZ6DQA/1)

Answer (score 0):

Use square brackets to match any characters in the list. `+` for matching 1 or more of the preceding group. You can use `{0,1}` to match 0 or 1 of a character/group. Use `*` instead if you want 0 or any number of spaces. You don't need the parenthesis unless you are using the capture groups to do a replacement or rearrangement or something similar.

```
/^[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{0,1}-\s{0,1}[a-zA-Z0-9]+\s{0,1}-\s{0,1}\d+\s{0,1}-\s{0,1}\d{4}$/
```

It would be helpful if you gave some examples of things you want to match and things you don't want to match so that it could be tested. If you want to check if it's working in real time, the site [Regex101](https://regex101.com/) or similar sites can be useful.